# Facebook Connect login dialog not getting displayed on iphone with new facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios, fbconnect, uiwindow

I am using new new Facebook-ios-sdk did everything what is informed in README.mdown.  while running this app.  It didnt showed me anything.  But when i kept break point in show in Fbdialog here:

```
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow; 
if (!window) {
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]; 
}
```

If any one can help me out with this it will be really great.

thanks, 
    Aby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the APPID which we also need to provide in the plist.