# Warning: 'UIDevice' may not respond to '-isMultitaskingSupported'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, fbconnect, uidevice

I am working with new [FBConnect](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) for iPhone.  But I have followed the steps given.. but when i build it shows me this warning "Warning: 'UIDevice' may not respond to '-isMultitaskingSupported'"  and the app crashes.  I am using iphone simulator 4.1 and still it is showing me this warning.  If anyone can help me out with this it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Versions of iOS prior to 4.0 don't have this method, so you have to use `respondsToSelector` to first check that the method is present prior to calling it.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && [[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
    // Device supports multi-tasking...

}
else {
    // No such luck.
}
```

As such, whilst you're using the iPhone simulator 4.1, I'm guessing that you've set the iOS version to 3.2 (use the Version option on the Hardware menu to change this).

Comment: In your sample code, you forgot to handle the case where UIDevice responds to `isMultitaskingSupported` but returns false. Also, the hardware setting in the simulator has nothing to do with the warning. Check "iOS Deployment Target" in your project or target build settings.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) .  As i have used the FBconnect which have the FBApp Login dialog box.  I tried to see if this works with this new FBconnect to so that i can use it on both 3.2 as well as 4.0.  But i got stucked here  
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];  App is crashing here.. :(.

Comment: @Anomie True - I was just trying to illustrate the various possible states. That said, I'll update the snippet. (You'd pretty much always check both in the same `if` anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for replying :) . As i have used the FBconnect which have the FBApp Login dialog box. I tried to see if this works with this new FBconnect to so that i can use it on both 3.2 as well as 4.0. But i got stucked here window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]; App is crashing here..

Comment: @Aby To be honest that sounds like a different issue, so I'd be tempted to open a new question, after first searching to see if someone's asked a similar question before.

Comment: i have already asked the question but didnt got any reply.  Check [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225317/facebook-connect-login-dialog-not-getting-displayed-on-iphone-with-new-facebook-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can Add below mention methode yo your Project to check If device support multi threading before any action

```
- (BOOL) isMultitaskingSupported
{
    BOOL result = NO;
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

    if (device != nil)
    { 
        if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] == YES)
        { 
            #ifdef __IPHONE_4_0 
                #if (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0)
                    result = [device isMultitaskingSupported]; 
                #endif
            #endif
        } 
        return(result);
    }
}
```

This will return Bool i.e True in case device supports Multitasking